# fatal error: sapnwrfc.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de instalar la librería sapnwrfc para python y obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy ejecutando:  sudo python setup.py build
No he podido solucionar esto, ¿alguien que me eche una mano por favor?

Comment: Se me ocurre que te puede estar faltando instalar el "SAP NW RFC SDK".

Comment: [Installation of sapnwrfc for python on Linux and Unix](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EmTech/Installation+of+sapnwrfc+for+python+on+Linux+and+Unix)

Comment: Gracias tienen razon, pero al parecer para instalar el NW RFC ocupo una clave.